# DynamoDB how to query by createdAt when partition key and sort key are already defined

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I already have GSI set to author as partition key and status as a sort key and use them to query the data I need. However, I can't figure out to sort my return data by chronological order.

DynamoDb table

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id | post  | author  | status  | createdAt   |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | post1 | author1 | publish | 2019-12-10  |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2  | post2 | author2 | draft   | 2019-12-11  |
-----------------------------------------------
| 3  | post3 | author1 | publish | 2019-12-12  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

and the query

```
var params = {
            TableName : "TABLENAME",
            IndexName: "gsi-authorStatus",
            KeyConditionExpression: "author = :author AND status = :status",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":author": JSON.stringify(event.bodyJSON.author),
                ":status": JSON.stringify(event.bodyJSON.status)
            }
        };

        dynamo.query(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error with ', err);
                context.fail(err);
            } else {
                context.succeed(data);
            }
        });
```

My query give me the data where author and status are matching but it give me a data in a random order. It is possible to use `createdAt` to make the return data order by latest?

Comment: Create a new GSI with createdAt as a sorted key, or order your data by your code instead of DB engine.

Comment: @hoangdv Thank you for the comment. I have to use author and status for the partition and sort key in order for me to get the data I need. Don't think ordering data in front-end will work since the returning data is all random with a multiple paginations.

Comment: Author as partition key, createdAt as sort key, include status as projected field and filter results by status

Comment: @AdrianPraja Yes, that's one way then run the query again till it gets certain number of result. However, I'm trying to see if there's a better way to do this :)

Comment: I don't see other options except if you query all data and sort the results clientside